# react-native run-android hangs on scanning for folders

Tags: react-native

Trying to run `react-native run-android` just outputs:

`Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\Matt\sites\rg-calendar\node_modules (136ms)`

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try update with:

```
 npm i
```

and if doesn't work check what file(s) or folder(s) delete or edited wrongly !

if problem is about connecting to the real device first check the `adb` and `adb devices` , then try this code:

```
react-native run-android --deviceId {YOUR DEVICE ID IN ADB DEVICES}
```

Comment: first of all check you are in root directry :-)

Answer (score 2):

Me too had this problem,and i solved it by simply closing and opening the terminal after that i was able to successfully execute the react-native run-andorid

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being late, but hope it helps somebody.
It appears there are two ways to create a react native project.

1. `create-react-native-app`
2. `react-native init`

The first method is used when you want to use Expo to run your app, and the second is used when you want to run the app using `react-native run-android`. When I use method 1, trying to run `react-native run-android` behaves the same way yours did in that screen shot. Using method 2 allows me to run the app using the aforementioned method, which is what you tried to do.

Comment: Nice Observation! So to start the app in Expo, we need to simply do 'npm start'.